# Can property setter condition acitvate by constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, setter

I was expected that constructor can go into the setter condition, I have done the following attempts.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Iitem car = new Car(7000);
  
            Console.WriteLine($"cost={car.cost}");//expect output "too expensive",but actually show 7000
            car.cost = 7000;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    public interface Iitem
    {
        int cost { get; set; }
        string status {get;set; }
    }
    class Car:Iitem
    {
        private int mycost;
        public int cost 
        {
            get { return mycost; }
            set 
            { 
                if (value > 5000)
                {
                    mycost = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("too expensive");
                }
                    
                else 
                {
                    mycost = value; 
                }
            } 
        }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Car(int cost)
        {
            this.mycost = cost;
        }
    }
```

If I discard `car.cost=7000` from Main() function, then I can't get the output of **too expensive**.

Comment: Property names should start with an upper-case letter. The backing field should have the same name starting with a lower-case letter and possibly an underscore for additional clarity. If you do that then you won't make silly mistakes like this. ALWAYS strive to make your code clear and readable. Clearly you are not doing that with your current naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

you are not getting the desired result because you are setting the value directly into the variable "mycost" in the constructor. Replace it with this.cost = cost;

Comment: "value" in setter represents the value assigned to the property. in your case "value" would represent the integer value that you would set to the cost property of the Car class. It does not matter from where you are setting the value for the property. In your case you will be setting it inside the constructor and the value is being passed from the main function to the constructor.